# Roof Structural Issues

Tags: structural, roofing

We are in the process of buying a house and our inspection report came back with some separation in the trusses of the roof on one side of the home.

I don't anything about roofs. Can someone provide some info as to the gravity of this issue?

Comments from the inspection are
"Any damage in the truss reduces the structural integrity of the system. Repair or replace by a professional building contractor."

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that the inspector has told you all about the gravity of it, what more do you want?

Comment: Get an estimate of cost to fix, wave that and the photos at the seller, and try to get them to discount the price enough to pay for that work. Or decide whether you like the house enough to buy it at the asked price and have it fixed later.

Comment: Just my opinion, the issues in the attic, that was built that way, has been there for decades. If the roof where it meets the ledger is going to drop, it would have by now. The gap in the ridge board is housed on either side by rafters, a common practice. The delamination of the joist is from what I can see is superficial. I can tell no more than that from the pictures. If that is all the inspector found, sometimes they have to cite something to make their $300+ trip seem worth it. Besides, if you are buying, the seller should be the one to have issues with this.

Comment: Is this house built in 1950s or 1960s?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the cracking in the rafter (sister it if you're really worried), but the sagging joint in what should be a ridge beam is a little troubling.